# Get seconds from a date to end of month PHP

Tags: php, seconds

Pulling a date of subscription from an sql database table we want the customer to have until the end of the month one year later to make a payment. The subscription is just some date within a month. The one year later part is easy, figuring out where the end of that month is and adding it, in seconds, to the one year part is giving me problems.

The date is stored as the number of seconds from unix ground zero. How do I find the number of seconds from that value to the end of that month? I've tried converting the date value to an actual date using `m-i-Y`

End of Month:

```
$expDate = date('m-i-Y',$row1["renewDate"]);
```

This works. I get the last day of that month in string form. But if I try:

```
$endOfMonth = strtotime($expDate);
```

Doesn't work....

echo'ing `$expDate` shows the last day of the month in string form.

echo'ing `$endOfMonth` returns nothing...

Thanks for any thoughts on this.

Comment: `i` denotes minutes (with leading zeroes). I think you want `t` to find the last day of the month. [Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). If you really want things down to the second, you'll have to force the `$expDate` to midnight as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strtotime` doesn't work properly with arbitrary date formats. You have two options:

1. Use `date_create_from_format` to parse custom date formats.
2. Convert your string to `Y-m-d` format which `strtotime` understands
   automatically.

For example:

```
$date = date('Y-m-t', $row1["renewDate"]);
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
```

P.S. As mentioned in comments, you should use `t` instead of `i`.

Answer (score 0):

You can play around with something like this.  If the database has Epoch time then you can use the '@' symbol to convert it to a date.  You can get the subscription date that way, and also the end of the subscription month date using m/t/Y.  You can convert that back to DT and then to UNIX time with get Timestamp.  Looks like it works for time = 1560961801.

```
$row1["renewDate"] = 1560961801;
$unixfromDB = $row1["renewDate"];

$date = new DateTime('@' .$unixfromDB); // your UNIX timestamp.     
$subdate =  $date->format( 'm/d/Y' ); // subscription date

$endmonth = $date->format( 'm/t/Y' ); // end of month date
$endmonth = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $endmonth);
$endmonth = $endmonth->getTimestamp();  // UNIX timestamp for end of month.

echo ($endmonth - $unixfromDB) / (60 * 60 *24);  // days to end of month
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `mktime()` instead of `strtotime()`.

```
<?
/* establish variables */
$now=time();    // epoch seconds right now
$expDate = date('m-t-Y', $row1["renewDate"]);   //note the switch to 't' as suggested by @ehymel
$eom = mktime($expDate);    // converts 'end of month' date into epoch seconds

/* results */
$secondsleft = $eom - $now;     // number of seconds until the end of the month
echo $secondsleft;  // return results
?>
```

Comment: thanks everyone, yeah, the 'i' was a typo... mktime($expDate) worked (I thought I tried that...oh well)...it's the simplest and does what I need. Thank you all again!

Comment: Would love to have you hit that checkmark on my answer. Glad this worked for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

mktime($expDate) unfortunately didn't work, at least with CentOS6.9. Even with the expdate variable it still returned current system time.

Using the date format that strtotime would recognize, Y-m-t, did work correctly. Thanks user1597430...